# MDX Query to return data from the same Measure in different columns

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I have an MDX query running againts a SSAS cube that looks like this

```
select non empty crossjoin([A].[B].[C], [A].[B].[D], [A].[B].[E]...) on rows,
[Measures].[Balance at Year End] on columns
from [Finance]
where [Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2015]
```

And it returns the list of departments by hierarchy and their year end balances.

I am trying to add the Balance at the end of 2014 and 2013 as another columns in the same table and can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for that.

```
where {[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2015],[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2014],[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2013]}
```

returns me a summed column. I am using the SQL Server Management studio to run the queries and later plan to put it into Excel using the hack from http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2009/12/18/binding-an-excel-table-to-the-results-of-an-mdx-query/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way to get this to work by doing a crossjoin on the Balance for the columns.

```
 crossjoin([Measures].[Balance at Year End],{[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2016],[Date].[Fiscal].Year.&[2015],[Date].[Fiscal].[Year].&[2014]}) on columns
```